# How to create flat file from toad for oracle using script OR stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad, flat-file

I need to create a flat file using script/stored procedure in toad for oracle. I can't use UTL_FILE here because of the privilege reason.

Please do not suggest me export wizard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-format-query-results-with-the-set-sqlformat-command

Comment: I believe SPOOL will work in TOAD if you run the file as a script.

Comment: Is there any way to create SP and run it automatically everyday?

Comment: Result of DBMS_OUTPUT can be saved into a file; right click the output and choose "Save". As of running the procedure every day: use DBMS_SCHEDULER (or DBMS_JOB).

Answer (score 0):

Creating an external table that writes into a file might be an option too: [External Table Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)
The advantage is you can use/execute it anywhere (Toad, procedure call in DB, SQL console, etc)
If you need it only once or a few times I would use as already mentioned: spool file or the dbms_output package.